# Python / Pygame - Get a square to change colour with classes

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am making a little project for a Battleships game, but I am having a little trouble with getting the code to understand when I click on the object, I want it to change colour.

So far I have this class:

```
class Tile:
def __init__(self, xstart, ystart, game_display, colour):
    self.tile = pygame.Rect(xstart, ystart, 50, 50)
    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, colour,  self.tile, 1)
    print(self.tile)

def ChangeColour(self, game_display, colour):
    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, colour,  self.tile, 0)
```

I create the board using this function I made:

```
def new_board():
global board
xstart = 70
ystart = 50
#pygame.draw.rect(game_display, BLACK, (70, 50, 500, 500), 3)
for square in range(PLAYER_NUMBER_SQUARES):
    board.append(Tile(xstart, ystart, game_display, BLACK))
    xstart += 50
    if xstart == 570:
        ystart += 50
        xstart = 70
return board
```

So far, I has added the square / rectangle objects to the list "board", when the player clicks, I get the pixel and use this method to get which square it is that has been clicked:

```
def get_x_number(x):
index = None
if x >= 70 and x < 120:
    index = 70
if x >= 120 and x < 170:
    index = 120
if x >= 170 and x < 220:
    index = 170
if x >= 220 and x < 270:
    index = 220
if x >= 270 and x < 320:
    index = 270
if x >= 320 and x < 370:
    index = 320
if x >= 370 and x < 420:
    index = 370
if x >= 420 and x < 470:
    index = 420
if x >= 470 and x < 520:
    index = 470
return index

def get_y_number(y):
index = None
if y >= 50 and y < 100:
    index = 70
if y >= 100 and y < 150:
    index = 120
if y >= 150 and y < 200:
    index = 170
if y >= 200 and y < 250:
    index = 220
if y >= 250 and y < 300:
    index = 270
if y >= 300 and y < 350:
    index = 320
if y >= 350 and y < 400:
    index = 370
if y >= 400 and y < 450:
    index = 420
if y >= 450 and y < 500:
    index = 470
return index
```

(I know this is a slightly more long winded way, but if there is a better way, let me know, tried loops, couldn't get it to work.)

Finally, I get to where it will get the clicked square, however it doesn't change the square, this is because when I index the square out of the list, it returns this: `<__main__.Tile object at 0x068A5590>`

How can I get it to return the pygame.Rect rather than this? I have had a look into classes, tried `__repr__` and `__str__` and had no joy, if someone can assist me, that would be great!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend making your `Tile` class a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) subclass and then adding all tiles to a [sprite group](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). That allows you to update and draw all sprites by calling `sprite_group.update()` and `sprite_group.draw(screen)`. Pygame sprites need an `image` (which has to be a `pygame.Surface` instance) and a `rect` attribute.

To check for collisions you can first iterate over the sprites in the sprite group and then use the `collidepoint` method of the sprite's `rect` to see if it collides with the mouse position, e.g. `sprite.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)` or `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`. If it collides with the mouse, call the `change_color` method and fill the `image` of the sprite with the new color (or you could also replace the image).

```
import pygame as pg


GREEN = pg.Color(0, 200, 90)
BLUE = pg.Color(0, 90, 200)


class Tile(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, position):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((50, 50))
        self.color = GREEN
        self.image.fill(self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=position)

    def change_color(self, color):
        self.color = color
        self.image.fill(self.color)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    # Create the tiles and add them to the all_sprites group.
    for y in range(10):
        for x in range(12):
            all_sprites.add(Tile((x*51, y*51)))

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            # If a mouse button was pressed.
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # Iterate over the sprites in the group.
                for sprite in all_sprites:
                    # Check if the sprite's rect collides with the mouse pos.
                    if sprite.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        # Finally change the color.
                        sprite.change_color(BLUE)

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: Here's a [pygame sprite tutorial](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=en#section_13). Of course you can also keep using a normal class and a list for the moment, however, sprites and groups are usually a bit more comfortable to use.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think it'd be substantially easier to use a loop (as you asked for suggestions).  In this method you get access to all tiles that were pressed, then you can execute `changeColor`.

```
import pygame

class Tile:
    def __init__(self, xstart, ystart, game_display, colour):
        self.tile = pygame.Rect(xstart, ystart, 50, 50)
        self.game_display = game_display
        self.colour = colour
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(game_display, colour,  self.tile, 1)

    def changeColour(self, colour):
        self.colour = colour
        self.draw()

    def doesHit(self,point):
        return self.tile[0] <= point[0] and self.tile[2] > point[0] and self.tile[1] < point[1] and self.tile[4] >= point[1]

def getTile(x,y):
    global board
    point = (x,y)
    for tile in board:
        if tile.doesHit(point):
            print("hit detected!")
            #now we have direct access to all tile information via tile!
```